# Find a key used to decrypt message with python functions

Tags: python, encryption, encoding, cryptography, rsa

There is a message: `0x1a67cad23ff2c5752f3d652d302a46427a27d5017a8064b32329ec1871L`
and python code that was used to encrypt this:

```
import codecs

def bytes_to_long(data):
    return int(data.encode("hex"), 16)

def rsa_encrypt(msg, e, n):
    return pow(bytes_to_long(msg), e, n)

def main():
    n = 29819592777931214269172453467810429868925511217482600306406141434158090
    e = 65537
    secret = "" #find this
    with codecs.open("encrypted.txt", "w") as output_file:
        output_file.write(hex(rsa_encrypt(secret, e, n)))

main()
```

The goal is to find a variable `secret` that has been used to produce `0x1a67cad23ff2c5752f3d652d302a46427a27d5017a8064b32329ec1871L`.
I made a small step:

```
>>> s = '0x1a67cad23ff2c5752f3d652d302a46427a27d5017a8064b32329ec1871'
>>> int(s, 16)
>>> `711889215226322184943193282945958342309634097071492255020318494300273L`
```

But I am not sure if I am on the good way. I guess there is some trick to do with properties of `codecs` module or `encode` function, but I'm stuck and don't know how to move forward.

Comment: Looks like public key crypto, you will have to brute force it to find it. Pretty much impossible depending on key length.

Comment: Is there meant to be a solution to this problem?  E.g. is it homework?  Generally with an n that large, you can't find the secret exponent.  You might be able to attack it if it is not using padding, but I think that will retrieve you the message not the secret exponent.

Comment: It is one of the job interview tasks I failed at and now I'm curious about a solution. I think it maybe related to pythons pow function or converting int < -- > hex in some way. What about this message retrieving attack?

Comment: n is easily factorable. It is simply the product of the first 41 primes. That makes it trivial to recover the decrypt exponent and decrypt the message.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Did you know this simply by looking at the number or did you guess and just try dividing?

Comment: @LukePark: I saw it was divisible by 2, so I checked if it was divisible by 3, then 5, and then I guessed that it was just a primetorial.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Ahh of course.  I didn't see anything other than "a very large number".  Nice catch.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Can u please explain in more detail how to recover exponent and decrypt message? I am trying to do it with q = sum(frist_20_primes), q = (rest_prime_numbers_to_41th) but still have problems handling those big numbers...

Comment: Just use the textbook definition of [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)). Follow steps 3, 4, and 5 in [RSA Key Generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation) to compute `d` and you are done.